# How does one scrape a webpage for a URL with no apparent tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, tags

Total baby Python here..., so I apologize in advance. As a starter project, I'm attempting to create a script that scrapes this page "https://dockets.justia.com/search?parties=Novo+Nordisk".

The script seems to runs fine for the case_number, but I really need to also have it return a URL for the cases.  My question - as ludicrously and embarassingly simple as it might appear - is what do you use as a tag when it seems that there is no tag. I believe I read somewhere that using strings is a bad idea.  What am I overlooking? I don't believe that anything I've read on Stackoverflow or Learning Python applies.

The segment I'm trying to capture is the URL in

```
"<a href="https://dockets.justia.com/docket/puerto-rico/prdce/3:2023cv01127/175963" class="case-name"><strong>Government of Puerto Rico et al v. Eli Lilly and Company et al</strong></a>"
```

from "https://dockets.justia.com/search?parties=Novo+Nordisk".

I don't see any item tag or anything else to hang my hat on...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get("https://dockets.justia.com/search?parties=Novo+Nordisk").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
cases = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "has-padding-content-block-30 -zb")

for case in cases:
    case_number = case.find("span", class_ = "citation").text.replace(" ","")
#    case_url = case.find["href"]
    print(f"Case No.: {case_number.strip()}")
#    print(f"Case URL: {case_url}")

    print("")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There actually is a tag with case url. You can find it by looking up for: `case_url = case.find("a", {"class": "case-name"})["href"]`

Comment: Oh good god! I've been staring myself blind at this all day - and there it is! Thanks so much for your help!